# TLS with syslog-ng 3.2.5

Tags: ssl, syslog-ng

Does `syslog-ng` 3.2.5 from EPEL 6 (for CentOS 6) support TLS? I cannot get it to work at all; here is what I'm using:

```
source s_network {
    tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514)
        tls( key_file("/etc/ssl/server.key")
             cert_file("/etc/ssl/server.crt")
        )
    );
};
```

I do a syntax check and it fails at `tls(`:

```
# syslog-ng --syntax-only
Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/lib64/syslog-ng', module='afsql'
Error parsing afsocket, syntax error, unexpected LL_IDENTIFIER, expecting ')' in /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf at line 24, column 9:

        tls( key_file("/etc/ssl/server.key")
        ^^^

syslog-ng documentation: http://www.balabit.com/support/documentation/?product=syslog-ng
mailing list: https://lists.balabit.hu/mailman/listinfo/syslog-ng
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it does not support tls:

```
# syslog-ng -V
...
Enable-SSL: off
```

Answer (score 0):

there are newer packages available that have SSL enabled. See the [syslog-ng download page](https://syslog-ng.org/3rd-party-binaries/)

Regards,

Robert Fekete

syslog-ng documentation maintainer